# Eclipse - marking 10 projects 'target' folder as derived

Tags: eclipse

I would like to mark all of my 'target' directories as 'derived' in Eclipse.  However I have about 10 projects and have to repeat the same process 10 times, is there any quick way of marking all 10 'target' folders as derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'derived'. However, Eclipse writes most settings to an XML file. Figure out which config file (e.g. `.classpath`) gets altered and then run sed over all your config files at once.

Comment: I think it actually stores the derived flag in the .metadata database

Comment: I love this plugin: http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv Small hint: you should disable egit feature to add derived folders automatically to .gitignore (Eclipse/Preferences/Git/Projects)

Answer (score 13):

I wrote the [AutoDeriv](http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv/) plugin to handle this specific task easily and efficiently. The short story:

1. list the resources you want to set as derived on a simple `.derived` text file
2. There is no 2.

Enjoy your clean workspace as resources are now correctly marked as 'derived'. The syntax is trivial, just like a .gitignore file.

For your specific case, create a `.derived` file at workspace root, write `target` in it, and your done.

I hope you will like it =)

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to set the Derived flag automatically, see [Where does Eclipse store information about which files are "Derived"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902357/where-does-eclipse-store-information-about-which-files-are-derived)

This is sad as I have to mark 20 subfolders as "Derived" each time I clone my project on a new machine. If you do it manually too, use the keyboard:

- Alt-Enter
- Alt-v
- Enter
- Cursor down
- repeat

Comment: There is a plugin on github that allows you to use the 'derived' feature by file, like .gitignore does for example. Disclamer: I wrote it. http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv/

Comment: @johand. I tried your plugin. Installation was fine. Adding ".derived" file added my folders. Then i looke dinto "properties" of these folders but the derived marker was not checked. I am using STS Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE based on Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Pleas add installing AutoDeriv plugin as an answer as this is really the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You got to remove third line from each .classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

I.e. remove <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>

Comment: this is what eclipse does when you manually mark 'target' as 'derived'.

Comment: But is the reverse true? Will removing it somehow mark target/classes as derived? How and why? And won't that make src/main/java no longer be a source folder?